# Qt show application, if currently running

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm creating a single instance app, which is minimised to system tray, I want to show the currently running instance, then quit the new one. How can I create this functionality?

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QQuickWidget>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QSystemSemaphore>
#include <QSharedMemory>

// Declare a user-defined data type to work with an icon in QML
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)
Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QSystemSemaphore semaphore("deploy", 1);  // create semaphore
    semaphore.acquire(); // Raise the semaphore, barring other instances to work with shared memory

#ifndef Q_OS_WIN32
    // in linux / unix shared memory is not freed when the application terminates abnormally,
    // so you need to get rid of the garbage
    QSharedMemory nix_fix_shared_memory("deploy Shared Memory");
    if(nix_fix_shared_memory.attach()){
        nix_fix_shared_memory.detach();
    }
#endif

    QSharedMemory sharedMemory("deploy Shared Memory");  // Create a copy of the shared memory
    bool is_running;            // variable to test the already running application
    if (sharedMemory.attach()){ // We are trying to attach a copy of the shared memory
        // To an existing segment
        is_running = true;      // If successful, it determines that there is already a running instance
    }else{
        sharedMemory.create(1); // Otherwise allocate 1 byte of memory
        is_running = false;     // And determines that another instance is not running
    }
    semaphore.release();

    // If you already run one instance of the application, then we inform the user about it
    // and complete the current instance of the application
    if(is_running){
        return -1;
    }

    // Register QSystemTrayIcon in Qml
    qmlRegisterType<QSystemTrayIcon>("QSystemTrayIcon", 1, 0, "QSystemTrayIcon");
    // Register in QML the data type of click by tray icon
    qRegisterMetaType<QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason>("ActivationReason");
    // Set icon in the context of the engine
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("iconTray", QIcon(":/deploy.png"));
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as Tray
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Extras 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QSystemTrayIcon 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    id: application
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Test")

    // system tray

    QSystemTrayIcon {
        id: systemTray

        // Initial initialization of the system tray
        Component.onCompleted: {
            icon = iconTray             // Set icon
            toolTip = "Deploy App"
            show();
            if(application.visibility === Window.Hidden) {
                application.show()
            } else {
                application.hide()
            }
        }

        /* By clicking on the tray icon define the left or right mouse button click was.
         * If left, then hide or open the application window.
         * If right, then open the System Tray menu
        * */
        onActivated: {
            if(reason === 1){
                trayMenu.popup()
            } else {
                if(application.visibility === Window.Hidden) {
                    application.show()
                } else {
                    application.hide()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Menu system tray
    Tray.Menu {
        id: trayMenu

        Tray.MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("Show App")
            onTriggered: application.show()
        }

        Tray.MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("Quit")
            onTriggered: {
                systemTray.hide()
                Qt.quit()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried creating an object, and set its running status to false or true in my `main.cpp` and in my `main.qml`  I check the value and quit the application.

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
SingleInstance singleInstance;

context->setContextProperty("SingleInstance", &singleInstance);
if (is_running) {
    singleInstance.running(true);
```

In my `main.qml` I check if the application is running.

```
Connections {
    target: SingleInstance
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    if (SingleInstance.running) {
        if(application.visibility === Window.Hidden) {
            Qt.quit()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What we ended up doing for single instance is to use [QLocalSocket](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlocalsocket.html) which is named pipe on Windows and local domain socket on Unix instead of `QSharedMemory` which requires more tweaking to get it right. Basically you do something like this to check if the server is running (`appName` must be unique application identifier, you can use e.g. [QCoreApplication::applicationName](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationName-prop)):

```
bool isSingleInstanceRunning(QString appName) {
    QLocalSocket socket;
    socket.connectToServer(m_appName);
    bool isOpen = socket.isOpen();
    socket.close();
    return isOpen;
}
```

If you get `false` you will create your own server (keep this instance during lifetime of your application):

```
QLocalServer* startSingleInstanceServer(QString appName) {
    QLocalServer* server = new QLocalServer;
    server->setSocketOptions(QLocalServer::WorldAccessOption);
    server->listen(appName);
}
```

You can also pass command line arguments from starting application to the already running instance - in starting instance of your application open the socket and send the command line parameters. On existing instance side just hook to [QLocalServer::newConnection](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlocalserver.html#newConnection) signal, open the socket and hook to [QLocalSocket::readyRead](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case `QtSingleApplication` has been created, which was adapted to Qt5, too:

https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtsingleapplication